# Pandas subtract dates to get a surgery patient length of stay

Tags: pandas, date

I have a dataframe of surgical activity with admission dates (ADMIDATE) and discharge dates (DISDATE). It is 600k rows by 78 columns but I have filtered it for a particular surgery. I want to calculate the length of stay and add it as a further column.
Usually I use

```
df["los"] = (df["DISDATE"] - df["ADMIDATE"]).dt.days
```

I recently had to clean the data and must have done it in a different way to previously because I am now getting a negative los, eg.

| DISDATE. | . ADMIDATE. | . los. |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2019-12-24 | 2019-12-08 | -43805. |
| 2019-05-15 | . 2019-03-26 | 50. |
| 2019-10-11 | . 2019-10-07 | 4. |
| 2019-06-20 | 2019-06-16 | 4 |
| 2019-04-11 | 2019-04-08 | 3 |

```
df.info()
```

df.info()

```
    <class '`pandas`.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 5 entries, 0 to 4
Data columns (total 78 columns):
```

5   ADMIDATE          5 non-null      datetime64[ns]
28  DISDATE           5 non-null      datetime64[ns]

<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 5 entries, 0 to 4
Data columns (total 78 columns):

```
5   ADMIDATE          5 non-null      datetime64[ns]
28  DISDATE           5 non-null      datetime64[ns]
```

I am not sure how to ask the right questions to the problem, - and why its only affecting some rows. In cleansing the data some of the DISDATES had to be populated from another column (also a date column) becuase they were incomplete, and I wonder if it is these which are negative due to some retention of the orig data soemhow even though printing the new DISDATE looks ok.

Comment: can you give the row for which you get the negative value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your sample works well with the right output (16 days for the first row)

Can you try that and check if the problem persists:

```
import io

data = df[['DISDATE', 'ADMIDATE']].to_csv()
test = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(data), index_col=0,
                   parse_dates=['DISDATE', 'ADMIDATE'])

print(test['DISDATE'].sub(test['ADMIDATE']).dt.days)
```

Output:

```
0    16
1    50
2     4
3     4
4     3
dtype: int64
```

**Update**

To debug your bad dates, try:

```
df.loc[pd.to_datetime(df['ADMIDATE'], errors='coerce').isna(), 'ADMIDATE']
```

You should see rows where values are not a right date.

Comment: Thats worked nicely on the actual data too. Apologies I am a surgeon with only limited python/pandas filtering skills. I can see the logic of using a string method. How can I convert that to a usable cleaning method and why did my method fail?.

Comment: I don't know. Force Pandas to cast to a datetime64: `df['DISDATE'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DISDATE'])` and `df['ADMIDATE'] = pd.to_datetime(df['ADMIDATE'])`. Does it work too?

Comment: ''' df['DISDATE'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DISDATE'])''' is fine but '''df['ADMIDATE'] = pd.to_datetime(df['ADMIDATE'])''' gives an error. - 
ParserError: Unknown string format: ADMIDATE. - perhaps thats it?

Comment: Are you sure you haven't typed `pd.to_datetime('ADMIDATE')`?

Comment: I updated my answer to help you to debug your problem.

Comment: I must have because I can’t replicate that now. I also found The problem. I had done substitution for null values after my pd.to_datetime in my cleaning script. Now I have it before everything is fine. Thanks v much for your help.